# Alter multiple lines in sed - BASH

Tags: bash, unix, sed

Haven't used much bash before and had no luck after searching around the web.

I'm trying to automatically configure some IP's in /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts so that the device name and IP address are increased. I have this file at the moment:

```
#!/bin/bash
COUNTER=0
NEXT=1
IP=124

      while [  $COUNTER -lt 120 ]; do
         sed 's/^DEVICE.*/DEVICE\=\"eth0\:'$NEXT'\"/' ifcfg-eth0:$COUNTER > ifcfg-eth0:$NEXT;
         sed 's/^IPADDR.*/IPADDR\=\"123.123.123.'$IP'\"/' ifcfg-eth0:$COUNTER > ifcfg-eth0:$NEXT;
         let IP=IP+1
         let COUNTER=COUNTER+1
         let NEXT=NEXT+1
      done
```

So this would be with eth0:0 set to IP 123.123.123.123 and eth0:0 as the device at default, and every following device (eth0:1, eth0:2 etc.) will have the device and IP incremented.

As far as I can tell, the issue is that sed will increment the device, but when issuing the second sed command, it's incrementing the IP, whilst resetting the device to whatever it is on eth0:0.

If somebody could help it'd be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because you're running the second `sed` command on the same file as the first (`ifcfg-eth0:$COUNTER`) instead of the *output* of the first (`ifcfg-eth0:$NEXT`).

It would make more sense to do both substitutions in a single execution of `sed`.  Just put `-e` in front of the actual sed command (`s/`...`/`),  and then you can do more than one thing by just adding more instances of `-e`:

```
sed -e 's/^DEVICE.*/DEVICE\=\"eth0\:'$NEXT'\"/' -e 's/^IPADDR.*/IPADDR\=\"123.123.123.'$IP'\"/' ifcfg-eth0:$COUNTER > ifcfg-eth0:$NEXT
```

Comment: FYI: instead of `sed -e 'command' -e 'another command' ...` you can do `sed 'command;another_command;...'`.  Saves some typing.